# Git Merge using Git bash commands

Tags: github

I need to backfill the code from one path to other path. How can I perform the merge of two branches in git hub using commands?

I used the command git merge branch name, but the code is not getting backfilled.

git merge -branchname

Comment: What do you mean by "backfill"? What exactly have you tried, what exactly is not working yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will have to first fetch the latest code on branches with command

```
- git fetch
```

And now you can merge the latest code in you local branch with command

```
-git merge origin/branch-to-be-merged
```